# Reduce brightness of colors in android?

Tags: java, android, colors

I am working with AChart Engine.

And set the colors at runtime dynamically.

**Here is my code,**

```
private int getRandomColor() {

    Random rnd = new Random(); 
    int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));   
    return color;
 }
```

**My problem is I get brightness color also(randomly).**

**So how to avoid brightness color only?**

**My output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and you want to avoid bright colours you have to change this line:

```
int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
```

to those lines:

```
int MAX_LEVEL = 128;
int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(MAX_LEVEL), rnd.nextInt(MAX_LEVEL), rnd.nextInt(MAX_LEVEL));
```

This will result in only darker colours being generated.

If you want only light colours just do it like this:

```
int BASE_LEVEL = 128;
int MAX_LEVEL = 128;
int color = Color.argb(255, BASE_LEVEL + rnd.nextInt(MAX_LEVEL), BASE_LEVEL + rnd.nextInt(MAX_LEVEL), BASE_LEVEL + rnd.nextInt(MAX_LEVEL));
```

Comment: @Rich s answer provides more flexible way of controlling desired parameters though.

Answer (score 5):

You might be better to use the HSB (Hue, Saturation, Brightness) color space rather than RGB.  You can use [getHSBColor()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getHSBColor(float,%20float,%20float)) instead and hard-code the saturation and brightness to keep them all the same, just randomizing the color.

```
private Color getRandomColor() {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return Color.getHSBColor(rnd.nextFloat(), 0.5f, 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: `private Color getRandomColor() {
         Random rnd = new Random();   
         return Color.getHSB(rnd.nextFloat(), 0.5, 0.5);
    }` then you can edit the two 0.5 values to taste.

Comment: method getHSB(float, double, double) is undefined for the type Color